# jquery ajax cakephp: change event for input text box displays all fields except city dropdown box

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, onchange, dropdownbox

When a user enters an email, the onchange event for the input text box fires and displays all the other fields except the city dropdown box. I noticed that $("#MerryParentCityId").val(result_array[5]); is having the value 81 but the respective city name that user is not getting displayed in MerryParentCityId dropdown box. The value for the state dropdown box is displaying fine. Can someone tell me on where i'm going wrong?

I have a feeling the problem is in the html form's MerryParentCityId dropdown box. But I have no idea on what changes to make there.

thank you.

add.ctp (partial form where city and state dropdown box is located)

```
<div class="input text required">
<label for="MerryParentEmail">Email</label><input name="data[MerryParent][email]" type="text" maxlength="30" id="MerryParentEmail" /></div>
<div class="input text required"><label for="MerryParentName">Parent/Guardian Name</label>
<input name="data[MerryParent][name]" type="text" maxlength="30" id="MerryParentName" /></div>
<div class="input text"><label for="MerryParentLandline">Landline</label><input name="data[MerryParent][landline]" type="text" maxlength="12" id="MerryParentLandline" /></div>
<div class="input text required"><label for="MerryParentMobile">Mobile</label><input name="data[MerryParent][mobile]" type="text" maxlength="10" id="MerryParentMobile" /></div>
<div class="input text required"><label for="MerryParentAddress">Address</label><input name="data[MerryParent][address]" type="text" maxlength="40" id="MerryParentAddress" /></div>
<div class="input select required"><label for="MerryParentStateId">State</label><select name="data[MerryParent][state_id]" id="MerryParentStateId">

<option value="">Choose one</option>
<option value="31">Andaman &amp; Nicobar</option>
<option value="4">Andra Pradesh</option>
<option value="25">Arunachal Pradesh</option>
<option value="13">Assam</option>
<option value="2">Bihar</option>
<option value="30">Chandigarh</option>
<option value="16">Chhattisgarh</option>
<option value="32">Dadra &amp; Nagar Haveli</option>
<option value="33">Daman &amp; Diu</option>
<option value="27">Delhi</option>
<option value="24">Goa</option>
<option value="7">Gujarat</option>
<option value="15">Haryana</option>
<option value="19">Himachal Pradesh</option>
<option value="17">Jammu and Kashmir</option>
<option value="12">Jharkhand</option>
<option value="8">Karnataka</option>
<option value="11">Kerala</option>
<option value="34">Lakshadweep</option>
<option value="5">Madhya Pradesh</option>
<option value="1">Maharashtra</option>
<option value="22">Manipur</option>
<option value="21">Meghalaya</option>
<option value="28">Mizoram</option>
<option value="23">Nagaland</option>
<option value="10">Orissa</option>
<option value="29">Puducherry</option>
<option value="14">Punjab</option>
<option value="9">Rajasthan</option>
<option value="26">Sikkim</option>
<option value="6">Tamil Nadu</option>
<option value="20">Tripura</option>
<option value="35">Uttar Pradesh</option>
<option value="18">Uttaranchal</option>
<option value="3">West Bengal</option>
</select></div>
<div class="input select required"><label for="MerryParentCityId">City</label>
<select name="data[MerryParent][city_id]" id="MerryParentCityId">
</select></div>
<div class="input text required"><label for="MerryParentPostalCode">Postal Code</label>
<input name="data[MerryParent][postal_code]" type="text" maxlength="6" id="MerryParentPostalCode" /></div></fieldset><div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div><div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="data[_Token][fields]" value="d2ad0fe88cfdc6c730e0a5b8d95d84db40a24543%3A" id="TokenFields273660451" /></div></form>
```

jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){


      $("#MerryParentEmail").change(function(){
        //txt=$("#MerryParentEmail").val();
        email_id=$("#MerryParentEmail").serialize();
        //alert(txt);
        $.post("../students/get_parent_info",email_id,function(result_str){
        result_array=result_str.split('<br>');
          $("#MerryParentName").val(result_array[0]); 
          $("#MerryParentLandline").val(result_array[1]);
          $("#MerryParentMobile").val(result_array[2]); 
          $("#MerryParentAddress").val(result_array[3]);
          $("#MerryParentStateId").val(result_array[4]);
          $("#MerryParentCityId").val(result_array[5]);
          $("#MerryParentPostalCode").val(result_array[6]);
        });
      });

           $("#MerryParentStateId").change(function(){
        state=$(this).val();
        txt_str="state_id="+state;
        $.get("../students/getcities",txt_str,function(result){
            $("#MerryParentCityId").html(result).show();
        });
       });



 });

</script>
```

students_controller.php

```
function get_parent_info(){
//$this->layout=false;
 if (!empty($this->data)){

    $merryparent_info=$this->Student->MerryParent->getMerryParents($this->data['MerryParent']['email']);

    echo $merryparent_info['MerryParent']['name'].'<br>';
    echo $merryparent_info['MerryParent']['landline'].'<br>';
    echo $merryparent_info['MerryParent']['mobile'].'<br>';
    echo $merryparent_info['MerryParent']['address'].'<br>';
    echo $merryparent_info['MerryParent']['state_id'].'<br>';
    echo $merryparent_info['MerryParent']['city_id'].'<br>';
    echo $merryparent_info['MerryParent']['postal_code'].'<br>';
    }
}

function getcities(){
    $this->data['MerryParent']['state_id']=$_GET['state_id'];
    if (!empty($this->data['MerryParent']['state_id'])){
       $cities = $this->Student->MerryParent->City->getCities($this->data['MerryParent']['state_id']);
    //print_r($cities);
    foreach ($cities as $k=>$v){
        echo '<option value="'.$k.'">'.$v.'</option>';
    }

        /* foreach($cities as $optionValue){
            echo '<option>' . $optionValue . '</option>';
        }*/
    }else{
        $this->Session->setFlash('You didn\'t select a state!');
    }

}

function add(){
        //saves a new students information to db
        $states=$this->Student->MerryParent->State->getStates();
    $this->set('states',$states);

    //$cities=array();  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once I added the following code to $("#MerryParentEmail").change eventhandler,

```
                       $("#MerryParentStateId").val(result_array[4]);
          state=result_array[4];
          txt_str="state_id="+state;
          $.get("../students/getcities",txt_str,function(result){
            $("#MerryParentCityId").html(result).show();
            $("#MerryParentCityId").val(result_array[5]);
          });
```

The city dropdown box is getting populated and the respective city for the user is getting displayed.
thank you.

Comment: That looks better @vaanipala, though with a little more thought you should be able to achieve the same end with just one round trip to the server, not two. ie. by including the `getcities` output in the response to `$.post("../students/get_parent_info"`. Also be aware that not all browsers will dynamically insert options in bulk into a select element with `.html(...)`. You need to (a) replace the entire dropdown from `<select>` to `</select>` or (b) after clearing all current options, insert new options individually, in a loop, with (pseudocode) `dropdown.append(option)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Beetroot-Beetroot. I try that out later. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it should work.

I can only think that the value returned for `city_id` doesn't match any of the ids in the `#MerryParentCityId` select element.

Inspect the page's HTML and the `result_str`; look for a mismatch.

Or maybe `#MerryParentCityId` is incorrect.

Comment: result_str="Palaniappan K<br>044-77223399<br>9860662309<br>44 Megala Chowk<br>6<br>103<br>384733<br>". Where state_id=6 and city_id=103. Both values exist in the cities table. #MerryParentCityId is also correct. I have verified in the browser's source code.

Comment: Is there another element with `id="MerryParentCityId"` on the page?

Comment: No, no other elements with id="MerryParentCityId" on the page.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the HTML snippet for the city dropdown (ie the served HTML, not the php source) please.

Comment: So the City dropdown is empty!

Comment: Thanks a lot Beetroot-Beetroot. Now it is working! please see my answer. :)